# Special permissions in Windows 2012R2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, file-permissions, ntfs

I have a main folder named "2020".
I have a script that creates a subfolder with a file number and an address, and 5 sub-sub folders, like in the following example:

[image]

I would like:

1. to give read only and traverse folder for folder 2020
2. to give the following permissions to all the sub folders and files that will be created
   [image]

So basically, users cannot create files in "2020", but only in the sub-sub-folders of each sub folder (Correspondance, Documents facturation, etc.)

Comment: Could you reply if this answers your question, or mark the answer as answer?

Answer (score 0):

I would use Powershell, specifically Set-ACL. I couldn't find much documentation but here is some : https://ss64.com/ps/set-acl.html and https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-acl?view=powershell-7

It would look something like this :

**#Folder to Set Permissions on**

$Path = "C:\test"

**#Retrieve Current ACL**

$ACL = Get-Acl $Path

**#Object to add to ACL**

$Object = "TESTGROUP"

**#This will create an Access Control Entity (ACE) for the referenced Object with Traverse Permissions, applies to subfolders and files only, with allow.**

$Rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("$Object","Traverse", "ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit", "InheritOnly", "Allow")

**#This will add the ACE to the existing ACL so the permissions are added, not overwritten.**

$ACL.AddAccessRule($Rule)

**#You can continue adding more permissions by repeating the previous steps, for example if you want to add ListFolder permissions :**

$Rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("$Object","ListDirectory", "ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit", "InheritOnly", "Allow")

$ACL.AddAccessRule($Rule)

**#Then you can finally apply the new ACL with :**

Set-Acl $Path $ACL